# Visual Studio 2017 - Content from Form1 is also in Form2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem. The problem is, that when i make a second form inside of my project in Visual Studio 2017, the content from Form 1 will be in the 2nd form, interactible on build, but not movable or deletable in the editor. I don't know what to do to fix this.

If you know a way to fix this, let me know please. It really helps me out with stuff like this.

Comment: If you do "Add new item - Windows Form" the form should be empty, did you perhaps copy it? There is no way for us to know without any code or anything else.

Comment: Have you separate class for Form2 or you just create another object of Form1 class?

Comment: If it does indeed behave as you described, this sounds like a bug from VS. Try [cleaning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) your project.

Comment: You probably used the "Inherited Form" item template by accident.  Use Project > Add Windows Forms instead so you get a new class whose base class is Form instead of Form1.  Editing the code of the broken Form2 class ought to fix it as well, just change the base class and rebuild.

Comment: Cleaning the project actually worked. Thank you @MetaColon and others for your answers. They really help me :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug of Visual Studio.
You should try cleaning the solution (from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> 1. In **Solution Explorer**, choose or open the solution.
> 2. On the menu bar, choose Build and then choose **Clean Solution** to delete any intermediate and output files. With only the project and component files left, new instances of the intermediate and output files can then be built.